# Solr: Excluding certain documents from getting sorted

Tags: sorting, solr

I have a Solr query where i am trying to sort the results based on a certain field.

I want to modify it in such a way that only a particular set of documents get sorted and the remaining are simply appended to the end of the sorted list.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Please help.

Regards.

Comment: Is the particular set of documents you want to get sorted dependent on the query itself or do you know them in advance? If latter, you can use Paige Cook's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Sort by a particular field condition which is dynamic, you can boost the field with matching condition higher and sort by score.
for e.g. `bq=some_field:some_value^10`
This will boost the scores of the documents only matching the criteria.
Also, for all the other documents the score would be unchanged and would follow the boasted documents as is.

**EDIT** :-
you can boost on multiple fields e.g. `bq=string_array_field:some_value^10&bq=ranking^10` would boost the documents matching the value and the having higher ranking to the top.
The rest of the documents would follow.

Comment: Is it possible to sort by some other field using the boost query? I want to sort my results based on a custom numeric field named as 'Ranking'. The documents having a specific set of values for a string array field and having a higher value for ranking should appear first in the results.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. But the sorting does not seem to work properly. The array field i have is defined as:<arr name="format"><str>format1</str><str>format2</str></arr>. Some documents can have this field containing format3 and format4. The rank field is a float field having a numeric value. The lower this numeric value the higher the rank. The results should be sorted in such a way that the documents containing format1 and format2 should always appear higher than format3 and format4. I tried a query like this:  &bq=format:(format1 OR format2)^50&bq=ranking^50 but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

For each `<fieldType>` definition in your schema.xml you can set a `sortMissingLast="true"` option that would give you the desired sorting behavior. For your specific example, I would recommend creating a new field with the `sortMissingLast="true"` set and use then populate this additional field based on your given criteria and not setting a value for those documents you want to appear at the end when sorted.

Comment: Thanks everyone for providing your inputs. However, is there a possibility to handle this in the query itself based on certain fields existing in the document. Meaning, I have a string array value existing for each document and i want to sort only those documents which have some specific values in this array and append the remaining documents at the bottom of the result set. Is that doable?

Comment: To add on, the sort field used is a different one than this string array field.

Comment: Jayendra's answer is more appropriate for your use case of sorting based on a specific value in a string array.